# Invoking function when condition becomes true

Tags: javascript

is there any way to set function to invokes when the condition which isnt true since start becomes true? 
    For example- 
    `[code]http://jsfiddle.net/gq5x1dpe/2/[/code]` - how to set "torek()" to invokes automaticly  when the condition becomes true?`

Comment: You could try `Object.observe`?

Answer (score -1):

add an EventListener to your HTML, which manages the state of your HTML.
Within that listener function should be a condition to test whenever something has changed, once that is true, it can invoke torek().

If you want a more detailed example, tell me what behavior you seek, exactly.

This gets the functionality you seek, though will need some finetuning:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleButton')[0];
    button.addEventListener('click', checkMargin, true);

function checkMargin() {
    var iv = window.setInterval(check, 20);
    window.setTimeout(killLoop, 3000);
    function check() {
        var m = window.getComputedStyle(boxOne).getPropertyValue('margin-left');

        if (m === '30px' || m === '200px') {
            console.log('did something');
        } else {
            console.log('did nothing');
            console.log(m);
        }
    }

    function killLoop() {
        clearInterval(iv);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds as if OP has a variable which is `false`. When this variable becomes `true` a function needs to be triggered. I don't think you can do that with an eventListener.

Comment: yes, that can be done. The variables are set by other functions. and everything is triggered by a DOM event. He also manipulates his HTML in every case. I don't see why it wouldn't be possible, you failed to explain why, and I also don't see why you downgraded my reply when Im still waiting from the poster to add more information.

Comment: Hi , thanks for answers , but im quite newbie in this things so i would like to ask - how can i add EventListener in HTML, which manages the state of my HTML? the only thing that comes to my mind is window.addEventListener("load",torek(),true) but it would only check condition at the start / after page has already loaded , correct me if im wrong and again thanks for answers:)

Comment: You're right in what you just proposed. My thought was a tad more complex. Could you explain in which EVENTS you want torek to fire?

Comment: well simpy said , i would like the button to automaticly change innerHTMl if divs margin-left=30px or 200px.

Comment: Ah, that is not what I first thought ;)
In that case, I think putvande was right, an event listener won't work.
However, you could "loop" a function inside an interval with a timeout time equal to your transition-delay. It would "scan" the margin every x ms, and if it's equal to 30 or 200, could fire Torek.

Want me to write up an example?

Comment: I added some code snippet to my original answer, it should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks for code , but originaly i had it also with setInterval but it got buggy and broke whole code :/

Comment: you should clear the interval on click as well, before starting a new loop. I believe the buggy code is caused by multiple "loops" executing at the same time.